# Visual C++ how to export x64 DLL functions for Delphi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, 64-bit

I'm mainly a Delphi developer, and I've been using a DLL wrapper which interfaces with Logitech's G15 etc api DLLs to interact with the keyboard LCD screens.

Some years ago some guy made this wrapper to be used with delphi, basically a DLL interfacing with the Logitech lib and exporting the functions to Delphi. It has been working fine, however, it was 32-bit only.

I got the wrapper sources and tried to compile it for 64bit, but something's wrong. I set the platform to 64bit, changed the config etc accordingly (I think), and pointed the library paths to the Logitech 64bit .lib

The exports seem to be there, but when I try to load any with GetProcAddress I get an error "The specified module could not be found"

What's wrong?

[image]

```
// lgLCDWrapper.DLL
//
// A Wrapper-DLL for Delphi and other compilers who cannot include the original
// lcLcd.Lib provided by Logitech. These functions are needed to communicate with
// the graphical LCD of an Logitech G15-Keyboard.
//
// Code by Olaf Stieleke, May 1st, 2007
// Compiler Visual C++ 2005 Express Edition
// Hereby dedicated to Open Source under GPL-License.
//

//Make sure to set additional Include-Path to lglcd.h (found in Logitech-SDK-Folders)
//Make sure to set additional Library-Path to lglcd.lib (found in Logitech-SDK-Folders)

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <lglcd.h>
#include "lgLcdWrapper.h"


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD _cdecl lgLcdInitWrap(void)
{
    return lgLcdInit();
}

DWORD _cdecl lgLcdDeInitWrap(void)
{
    return lgLcdDeInit();
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdConnectAWrap(lgLcdConnectContextA *ctx)
{
    return lgLcdConnectA(ctx);
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdDisconnectWrap(int connection)
{
    return lgLcdDisconnect(connection);
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdEnumerateWrap(int connection, int index, lgLcdDeviceDesc *description)
{
    return lgLcdEnumerate(connection,index,description);
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdOpenWrap(lgLcdOpenContext *ctx)
{
    return lgLcdOpen(ctx);
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdCloseWrap(int device)
{
    return lgLcdClose(device);
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdReadSoftButtonsWrap(int device, DWORD *buttons)
{
    return lgLcdReadSoftButtons(device,buttons);
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdUpdateBitmapWrap(int device, lgLcdBitmapHeader *bitmap, DWORD priority)
{
    return lgLcdUpdateBitmap(device,bitmap,priority);
}
DWORD _cdecl lgLcdSetAsLCDForegroundAppWrap(int device, int foregroundYesNoFlag)
{
    return lgLcdSetAsLCDForegroundApp(device,foregroundYesNoFlag);
}
```

include file

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdInitWrap(void);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdDeInitWrap(void);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdConnectAWrap(lgLcdConnectContextA *ctx);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdDisconnectWrap(int connection);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdEnumerateWrap(int connection, int index, lgLcdDeviceDesc *description);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdOpenWrap(lgLcdOpenContext *ctx);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdCloseWrap(int device);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdReadSoftButtonsWrap(int device, DWORD *buttons);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdUpdateBitmapWrap(int device, lgLcdBitmapHeader *bitmap, DWORD priority);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD  _cdecl lgLcdSetAsLCDForegroundAppWrap(int device, int foregroundYesNoFlag);
```

stdafx.cpp

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    // stdafx.h : Includedatei für Standardsystem-Includedateien
// oder häufig verwendete projektspezifische Includedateien,
// die nur in unregelmäßigen Abständen geändert werden.
//

#pragma once

// Ändern Sie folgende Definitionen für Plattformen, die älter als die unten angegebenen sind.
// In MSDN finden Sie die neuesten Informationen über die entsprechenden Werte für die unterschiedlichen Plattformen.
#ifndef WINVER              // Lassen Sie die Verwendung spezifischer Features von Windows XP oder später zu.
#define WINVER 0x0501       // Ändern Sie dies in den geeigneten Wert für andere Versionen von Windows.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT        // Lassen Sie die Verwendung spezifischer Features von Windows XP oder später zu.                   
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 // Ändern Sie dies in den geeigneten Wert für andere Versionen von Windows.
#endif                      

#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS      // Lassen Sie die Verwendung spezifischer Features von Windows 98 oder später zu.
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410 // Ändern Sie dies in den geeigneten Wert für Windows Me oder höher.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE           // Lassen Sie die Verwendung spezifischer Features von IE 6.0 oder später zu.
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0600    // Ändern Sie dies in den geeigneten Wert für andere Versionen von IE.
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN     // Selten verwendete Teile der Windows-Header nicht einbinden.
// Windows-Headerdateien:
#include <windows.h>
```

Delphi code:

```
DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('lgLcdWrapperX64.dll');
  if DLLHandle = 0 then Exit(False);

  @lgLcdInit       := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'lgLcdInitWrap');
  if (not Assigned(lgLcdInit)) then ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
```

Comment: I believe you should put `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` before the definitions too.

Comment: question edited; the exports seem to be there, but GetProcAddress fails to load any (works fine in 32bit)

Comment: 32 bit and 64 bit processes use different search paths and (some) registry keys. For instance, 64 bit processes use system32, while 32 bit ones use SysWOW64 (on a 64 bit OS). A 32 bit process cannot load a 64 bit DLL, and vice versa. This is probably the origin of your problem - try using ProcMon to figure out where is the DLL searched for. Most chances are that it's not searched where you expect, or you're mixing 32 and 64 bit executables.

Comment: No, the app is 64bit, and I put the DLL in the same folder. LoadLibrary works fine, just GetProcAddress returns "The specified module could not be found", but the exports are there properly according to Dependancy Walker

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's the error you get from GetProcAddress, and that LoadLibrary has indeed succeeded? GetProcAddress looks for procedures, not modules. If it's indeed a procedure that isn't found, the exported functions might be mangled. Has a .def file been used in the 32 bit build?

Comment: Please, when you edit your question, edit it *as a whole*. Don't just add a note at the bottom which contradicts everything above it. If you find out that the information in the rest of your question was incorrect, then *remove* it. If someone reads your question **now**, what do they need to know or see? They don't need to see what the question looked like yesterday. They need to see what you want to ask **now**

Comment: Sorry you are right, I'll edit that. @eran, yes I'm sure. I get a handle to the DLL and last error is "The operation completed succesfully"; then GetProcAddress gets the other error.

Comment: Also, according to Dependency Walker (see screenshot above), the exported function names are correct.

Answer (score 2):

> I get an error "The specified module could not be found

That's not an error produced by GetProcAddress, you get that one from LoadLibrary().  Error code 126.  GetProcAddress fails with error 127, "The specified procedure could not be found".  So check your error handling code, it's probably got a bug.  And triple check that you use the correct path name for the DLL and that dependent DLLs are properly deployed, like the CRT dlls.

The only other relevant tidbit is the name decoration applied to exported functions in a 64-bit DLL.  Your client code surely used a name like "_lgLcdInitWrap" before, the leading underscore indicates that the __cdecl calling convention is in effect.  64-bit code is blessedly agnostic of calling conventions, there is only one.  Accordingly, exports are not decorated anymore, it will be just plain "lgLcdInitWrap".  Something you'd definitely see with a tool like dumpbin.exe /exports or depends.exe.

Comment: Erm no, the error comes after GetProcAddress:

(added code to main question at the end)

The first step passes fine, I get a handle to the DLL, then GetProceAddress raises the error.

Comment: I answered a MSVC C++ question, can't help you with Delphi problems.  Clearly there's something wrong, GetProcAddress can't generate an error about the module, it already has the module handle.  You passed it.

Comment: Been testing with a Delphi made 64-bit DLL, same code works fine there, just not with the C++ DLL. I know the error code is what I would get if LoadLibrary had failed, but that call actually passes fine, I get a DLL handle and no error, I don't know why GetProcAddress returns Module rather than Procedure in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. When I added the x64 platform in VS2010 it set 2 settings that cause the whole issue:

Project options > Linker > Advanced >
- Randomized Base Address
- Data Execution Prevention (DEP)

Disabling those 2 settings fixed it.

[image]

Comment: Disabling those two options is a major no-no security wise.